# git add . command not working

Tags: git, github, git-bash, gitlab

`git add .` is not working it got stuck as you can see the below image.
I am building an expo project and the directory structure is in the image.
Please help me with this problem.

I also tried `git add --all`, `git add -A` none is working

[image]

Comment: Sorry, we can't accept images of code or errors. Post those as text, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Try to add `node_modules` folder to gitignore `echo "node_modules" >> .gitignore` and then rerun `git add .`.

Comment: @iamdi yes thats work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the `node_modules` folder is not ignored and hence when we run `git add .` command git visit all your directory/files and sub directory/files which is not ignored in `.gitignore` hence it is taking so long time to process it as `node_modules` contains a large amount of files and folder.

Solution:

Create `.gitignore` file in root directory of project and
add `node_modules` folder to file `.gitignore`